# Vb SQL query in Access not working

Tags: vba, microsoft-access

I'm trying to have a drop down menu populate a list of items under a given selection. So far I am able to bring the entire table:

[Drop down list here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbQHC.png)

I'm having however, a hard time to fit in the "WHERE" statement that will parse the query with the group selected in the dropdown:

[Blank list when trying to add "WHERE"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzasX.png)

This is the code that works:

```
Private Sub catBox_Change()
Dim SQL As String
SQL = "SELECT CatQuery.[Tool Name], CatQuery.Category " _
& "FROM CatQuery;"
Me.toolBox.RowSource = SQL
Me.toolBox.Requery
End Sub
```

This is the code that does not work:

```
Private Sub catBox_Change()
Dim SQL As String
SQL = "SELECT CatQuery.[Tool Name], CatQuery.Category " _
& "FROM CatQuery" _
& "WHERE CatQuery.Category ='" & Me.toolBox.Column(0) & "';"
Me.toolBox.RowSource = SQL
Me.toolBox.Requery
End Sub
```

Comment: Probably `Me.toolBox.Column(0)` evaluates to "" (blank or null). You probably need to check the `Text` property or use the `ItemsSelected` property. Also, the easy way to evaluate your built string (`SQL`) is to put a break point immediately after assigning a value to it and then use the immediate window (or hover your mouse?) to print it. Also try using `Like` instead of `=`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/listbox-itemsselected-property-access

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the SQL string after assigning it?

You've omitted spaces between `FROM CatQuery` and `WHERE...`

Try:

```
SQL = "SELECT CatQuery.[Tool Name], CatQuery.Category" & vbNewLine & _
      "FROM CatQuery" & vbNewLine & _
      "WHERE CatQuery.Category = '" & Me.toolBox.Column(0) & "';"
```

Comment: Hi ThunderFrame. It still does not work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

When a `catbox_change` event is called, the `toolbox` has no focus and therefore values.
Is it possible to assign values from a cutbox?:

```
Private Sub catBox_Change()
Dim SQL As String
SQL = "SELECT CatQuery.[Tool Name], CatQuery.Category " _
& "FROM CatQuery" _
& "WHERE CatQuery.Category ='" & Me.catBox.column(x) & "';"
Me.toolBox.RowSource = SQL
Me.toolBox.Requery
End Sub
```

If not then you need the`RowSource` assigned to another dropdown list `toolBoxResult`:

```
Private Sub catBox_Change()
Dim SQL As String
SQL = "SELECT CatQuery.[Tool Name], CatQuery.Category " _
& "FROM CatQuery" _
& "WHERE CatQuery.Category ='" & Me.toolBox.Column(0) & "';"
Me.toolBoxResult.RowSource = SQL
Me.toolBoxResult.Requery
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi adarti. Can you elaborate more? I added more details to the question.